# How do I get the right string to work with Database connection

Tags: python, qt, mysql-python

I am using python Qt and MySQLdb and I got this problem:

In this function

```
def connection(self,username,password):
    try:
        self.conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user=username,passwd=password)
        return True

    except MySQLdb.Error:
        return False
```

When I enter manually the username and password it goes well but when I try to get it from a Qt interface using:

```
str(pass_text.text())
```

it couldn't connect. When I tried:

```
print str(pass_text.text())
```

it does print the write string. I am confused... can you help me please?

Comment: can you explain what is `pass_text.text()` ?

Comment: Remove the `try/except` block and show what the exception is that occurs. That will make it easier to help.